# Good data structure to hold a list

Tags: algorithm, list, binary-search-tree

I need to have a data structure that holds an ordered list. I need to have an insert, a delete operation, as well as a getPosition operation.

The getPosition operation is frequently called on successive element, for example I have the list:

```
[a0, a1, …, ak, ak', …, an]
```

I need very often to get `ak`'s index and then `ak'`'s index.

I was thinking that an algorithm similar to splay trees, but that would move the neighbors of visited elements as well could be efficient, but I couldn't find any reference. Do you have any suggestion?

EDIT:
I also need a fast insertion + deletion. Something in O(log(n)) is sufficient.

Comment: Once you have the position of `ak`, you have the position of `ak'`, no?

Comment: Yes, but an insertion or a deletion may have occured since you checked `ak` position, so the previously computed position may not be relevant anymore.

Comment: have a look at linux process scheduler. there is one pretty suit your condition. it's used in CFS(completely fair scheduler). it uses a RBTree, however, there is an extra doubly linked list to chain all nodes together in in-order traversal order. this redundancy can reduce successor and predecessor operation to `O(1)` while keeping delete and insert `O(lg n)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a [Skip List](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list)? This should allow you to keep an ordered list and give you O(log n) performance (on average) for insert, delete, and search.

In terms of optimizing searching for element `k+1`, perhaps just cache the last searched index and start your search from there.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>**A solution, but not a very good one:**</strike>

Since the `getPosition` operation is called "frequently", I think that your node should look like:

```
struct node {
    int key;
    int index;
    node *next;
    node *last;
}
```

And every time you add or delete a node you run over the remainder of the list and update the indexes.

**Better solution:**

You could use a tree struct where all nodes are kept in the leaf nodes, and each root holds the number of leafs under it. `Insert`, `Delete` and `getPostion` should be `O(log n)`.

Comment: Yes, but that means that insertion and deletion run in O(n), with n the length of my list while a binary tree would give me O(log(n)), but a slower getPosition. I'm updating the question to highlight the need to have a fast insertion and deletion as well.

Comment: and how would index help? you still have to iterate over all nodes

Comment: As for your better solution, I totally agree, but do you have any suggestion to benefit from the fact that neighbors of recently visited leafs are accessed shortly after?

Comment: Yes. Find their LCA and that should make it (not asymptotically) better. Worst case, their LCA is the root, and this will be useless. Also, every node can hold pointers to their neighbors and then if you get `ak'` right after `ak`, you can check if it the neighbor of the last one you just retrieved  and you know the position is +1 to what is was before